# Shopware 6 App - Custom Storefront Controller

Tags: shopware6

Is there a way to create a custom controller for the shopware storefront via an app?
If it is not possible to do in the latest shopware 6.4.13 maybe some official can share a roadmap for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using app scripts https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/custom-endpoints#storefront-endpoints

Comment: Does it serve as a "real" route / controller? Guess i have to play around to find the limitations and fits for my need.
But thanks a lot for that first helpful approach. Basically, this is the answer to my question.

Comment: Yep it acts like a normal controller